# class transformation of discriminated unions

Tags: typescript, class-transformer

I played around with `routing-controllers` and it's build-in class-transformer ability.  I tried to build an interface where I can perform a search query based either on a `location id` or `location coordinate`. So I intended to use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) as a body parameter and could not get it to work. (See last console output what I mean by 'not working')

As an example:

```js
interface LocationCoordinates {
    type: 'coordinate'
    longitude: number
    latitude: number
}

interface LocationId {
    type: 'id'
    id: number
}

class LocationRadius {
    data: LocationCoordinates | LocationId
    searchRadiusInKm: number
}

// raw input for LocationCoordinates
const rawLocationCoordinates = {
    data: {
        longitude: 22,
        latitude: 33
    },
    searchRadiusInKm: 30
}


// raw input for LocationId
const rawLocationId = {
    data: {
        id: 1
    },
    searchRadiusInKm: 30
}
// transfrom both raw inputs
const realLocationCoordinates = plainToClass(LocationRadius, rawLocationCoordinates);
const realLocationId = plainToClass(LocationRadius, rawLocationId);


console.log({
    coordinateType: realLocationCoordinates.data.type, // expect 'coordinate' but got 'undefinded'
    idType: realLocationId.data.type // expect 'id' but got 'undefinded'
});
```

Is there a way to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but you will need some changes:

1. `LocationId` and `LocationCoordinates` should be classes
2. You should add a `@Type` decorator to the input property. This allows `class-transformer` to handle the deserialization based on a specific discriminator parameter

```
class LocationRadius {
 @Type(() => Object, {
     keepDiscriminatorProperty: true,
     discriminator: {
         property: "type",
         subTypes: [
             { value: LocationCoordinates, name: "coordinate" },
             { value: LocationId, name: "id" }
         ]
     }
 })
 data: LocationCoordinates | LocationId
 searchRadiusInKm: number
}
```

3. You should add a `type` property to your input, in order to allow even TS to discriminate between the union:

```
 // raw input for LocationCoordinates
const rawLocationCoordinates = {
   data: {
       type: "coordinate",
       longitude: 22,
       latitude: 33
   },
   searchRadiusInKm: 30
}
```

You can see the result in this [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-transformation-of-discriminated-unions) I set up

Comment: Thank you so much! I must have overseen it. There is even an example in the readme. Thanks again!